# Unable to use patoolib after 'pip3 install patool'

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am using a macbook, and have `python3` installed and using `spyder`.

I have installed `patool` and it's listed in `pip3 list`.

When I import `patoolib` and run the program it says, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'patoolib'`

So I am not able to run the extract related programs.

```
import patoolib
import os
import glob

def extract_files(inputdir = '/Users/satishvadlamudi/Python_spyder_projects/zipped',outputdir = '/Users/satishvadlamudi/Python_spyder_projects/extracted'):
    os.chdir(inputdir)
    archives = glob.glob('*.gz')
    #print(archives)
    if not os.path.exists(outputdir):
        os.mkdirs(outputdir)
    files = os.listdir('/Users/satishvadlamudi/Python_spyder_projects/extracted')
    print (files)
    for archive in archives:
        if archive[:-3] not in files:
            patoolib.extract_archive(archive, outdir = outputdir)
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstall, then install? if you're using Condo, then you may need to clear caches as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "pip" is also a python module. If you see `pip3 list` give you the module installed but `python3` complaint about ModuleNotFoundError, you may want to check if `pip3` and `python3` mean the same thing.

Try with `python3 -m pip list -v`, which the `-v` tells you the installed location as well. If you see the module there, then the same `python3` interpretor should be able to find the module. If not, you may want to consider setting up `PYTHONPATH` env variable.

Comment: With "python3 -m pip list -v" found patool and pyunpack, but still show "patool not found".
--------
patool      1.12    C:\Users\mi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages pip
pip         23.2.1  C:\Users\mi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages pip
pyunpack    0.3     C:\Users\mi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages pip

Answer (score -1):

In order to **import** :

```
import patoolib
```

you need to **install** patool first :

```
pip install patool
```